# Wysiwyg - Copy/Pasted content in editor should be in plain text

Tags: wysiwyg

I have a Wysiwyg editor, and users copy/paste content from other websites into the editor. Mostly test.

When this happens, Wysiwyg keeps the fonts from the website the user copy/pasted from. I want the content to be compatible with the fonts the website is using. In other words, I want the copy/pasted content to keep everything from the website the user copy/pasted from. Everything except the fonts.

Comment: Maybe [this posting](https://superuser.com/questions/1376470/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-pasting-without-formatting-in-ms-word) will help you.

Comment: No, thanks, but users won't know that. I am looking for some filter or javascript that I can add to Wysiwyg

Comment: Well, to complete this question, at least you'll have to specify the source and destination programs/platforms/apps/OS. Your question may be referring to some Drag-and-Drop-handler...?

Comment: more like a copy/paste handler, since I want to filter out the <font> tab when a user pastes information from another website into the editor.